# Bulk move items from deleted to inbox in Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

So I was checking my Hotmail account this morning, and not paying very much attention when I attempted to mark the whole inbox as read.  Instead, I "emptied" the inbox folder, which put everything in deleted items.  At the moment, everything is still there, but I'm looking for a way to undo this quickly.  I had over 6000 messages in my inbox, and so far I've only been able to drag them 35 at a time back from the deleted items folder.  Is there any way to increase the number of messages I can see at a time, or to simply bulk-move all the items from deleted into the inbox?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to push the 7-day window before Hotmail removes them from the deleted items, so I moved them manually today.  Still, I would like to know if anyone can figure out how to do this because I'm sure I'm not the only one that's done this, or that it's the last time I'll do something like this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected I just did it again, but this time I managed to figure out how to fix it.  Can't guarantee that this works exactly at Hotmail.com, but it definitely works at Outlook.com (the "new Hotmail" you can convert to).

To put all your deleted messages back in your inbox, go to the deleted items folder.  Click the checkbox at the top of the list, which by default selects only the 35 showing on that page.  Where the content of a single message would normally appear, you should now see the option **Select Everything in your Deleted folder**.  Click this and it will change to say **Everything selected**.  Now you can drag the list of emails back into your inbox.  It won't show you the specific number of messages selected, it will just say **Selected Items**.  This will take a minute or two if you have thousands of messages, but it will eventually finish and your whole deleted inbox will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ALL (CTRL A) - Right Click over selected and select MOVE TO; INBOX. Should complete in in about a minute depending on how many.